# Standalone Database Option that works well with EF and is easily deployable?

Tags: database, vb.net

I recently started a Winforms VB.NET application that uses a mysql database to store information. Problem is this is a standalone system no network access to the database is needed. And installing mysql server, along with the connector has become a great burden. Is there a viable alternative database engine that will be non-transactional, and EF still works with.  This database just needs to keep up with client details, payment History, and related items..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Compact might work for you, depending on it's [limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx).  If not, SQL Server Express will work fine